# If the heat exchanged is different for reversible and irreversible processes, how can enthalpy be a state function?

Tags: thermodynamics

From the definition of Gibbs free energy, we can write for an irreversible process:

$dG=dH-TdS<0$

With $TdS=\pu{q_{rev}//T}$ this becomes:

$dH-dq_{rev}<0$

Since G is defined for constant (p,T) $dH=dq$, in the case of an irreversible process we can write $dq=dq_{irrev}$, so:

$dq_{irrev}-dq_{rev}<0$

Or, by default:

$dq_{rev}>dq_{irrev}$

BUT: since $dH=dq$, this would mean:

$dH_{rev}>dH_{irrev}$

**Which is in contradiction with the fact that H is a state function (the path between 2 states shouldn't matter)!** What am I missing here?

Comment: When you write dG=dH-TdS, you are implying that T is constant.  Did you mean to imply this?  Can you give a specific process example to focus on to illustrate what you are asking?

Comment: The definition of Gibbs free energy always implies constant T. It is valid for all processes assuming constant T and p.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The definition of Gibbs free energy is G=H-TS, so dG=dH-TdS-SdT=VdP-SdT

Comment: Can whoever downvoted this question tell me why? Or answer the question at least? I asked this to quite some people with knowledge of thermodynamics and they weren't able to answer me so it must be a valid question.

Comment: It wasn't me.  I will try to help you.

Comment: From Wikipedia: 
In thermodynamics, the Gibbs free energy (IUPAC recommended name: Gibbs energy or Gibbs function; also known as free enthalpy[1] to distinguish it from Helmholtz free energy) is a thermodynamic potential that can be used to calculate the maximum of reversible work that may be performed by a thermodynamic system at a constant temperature and pressure (isothermal, isobaric).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86954/discussion-between-chester-miller-and-stikke).

Comment: I was hoping we could continue our discussion.  I know I can help you if only you are willing to participate.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the OP does not seem to be active in this tread any longer, I'm going to provide an answer anyway, since it seems like such an interesting question.

First of all, even if a closed system undergoes a process in which it is in contact with a constant pressure surroundings throughout the entire process, and this pressure is the same as that of the system in its initial and final states, the heat absorbed Q is still not necessarily equal to the change in enthalpy unless PV work is the only form of work being done. For example, if there is a stirrer doing work to agitate the system (and cause irreversible viscous heating), and no PV work occurs, and the system is in contact with a constant temperature bath throughout, the change in enthalpy will be equal to zero, but Q will be equal to minus the amount of work that the stirrer does on the system.

Secondly, assume that throughout the irreversible process, the system undergoes a change in which it is in contact with a single constant temperature reservoir at the same temperature as the initial and final temperatures of the system, and is also in contact with a constant pressure surroundings at the same pressure as that of the system in its initial and final states.  But consider that a reversible process between the same initial and final end states does not have to resemble the irreversible path in any way whatsoever, as long as it matches the initial and final temperatures and pressures (and species concentrations if chemical reaction is involved).  Even if the boundary temperature for the reversible path is held constant at the same value as the irreversible path, the pressure of the surroundings during the reversible path definitely does not have to be (and will not be) constant throughout the reversible path.  And, given that this is the case, the heat Q for the reversible path would not be required to be the same as that for the irreversible path, even if the enthalpy changes for both paths is the same.  In virtually all cases, it will actually not be possible to devise a reversible path at a constant surrounding pressure between the same pair of end states.  So the heat Q for the reversible path will not be equal to the change in enthalpy for the reversible path (and thus the change in enthalpy for the irreversible path).

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my inactivity first of all. Regarding the first point, ok true but let's assume only pV work. In the second point you make the case that qrev is not equal to q(irrev), which I agree with. But since H=pV+U=q-pdV+Vdp+pdV=q+Vdp, H equals q at constant pressure in absence of pV work. So saying q(rev) is not equal to q(irrev) is saying H(rev) is not H(irrev). And H is a state function (unlike q). That was the origin of my confusion.

Comment: Please don't use differentials for finite path lengths in irreversible processes.  It will lead you astray.  Now, let's focus on a specific irreversible process, and see how this plays out.  I am proposing we look at the irreversible expansion of an ideal gas, in which the gas is held in contact with a constant temperature reservoir at its initial temperature and in which we suddenly (at time zero) drop the external pressure to a new constant value and then hold it at that value until the gas re-equilibrates.  Is this an OK case to consider?

Comment: The problem is that H is defined for constant pressure, usually H is used for processes involving a change in chemical potential. I guess an isobaric expansion would fit the definition of H (although for G as stated in the original question both T and p are constant)

Comment: H is not defined for constant pressure.  The definition of H is simply H = U+PV.  Are you saying you don't like the specific focal problem I proposed?  If not, it's your turn to propose a focal problem.

Comment: Here is an alternate irreversible process for you to consider.  I have a system that is going to react chemically.  There are two ideal gas reactants in separate chambers at the same pressure and temperature separated by a barrier.  The system is in contact with a constant temperature reservoir.  At time zero, the barrier is broken and the reaction is allowed to proceed.  The imposed pressure on the system is maintained constant at the initial value.  Compare the values of the heat transferred and the change in enthalpy for this irreversible with a reversible for the same end states.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but I started from the definition of G which does assume constant p,T. And for constant p dH=dq. Ok that's an interesting process, but I honestly don't know how to start with it. No pV work will be done here right? So the change in internal energy will be down to heat and chemical potential (making abstraction of other kinds of work). How do you make this reversible/ irreversible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87539/discussion-between-chester-miller-and-stikke).

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question is that, for an irreversible process, $\text{d}H \neq \text{d}q_\text{rev}$ under the given constraints (i.e., constant $T$ and $P$, $P_\text{sys} = P_\text{surr}$, only $PV$ work).  On the other hand, $\text{d}H = \text{d}q_\text{irrev}$ is valid.  As Chet Miller suggests in his answer, there is no reversible path for a change of composition at constant $T$ and $P$ (when there is only $PV$ work). Thus, while $\text{d}H = \text{d}q$ at constant $T$ and $P$, $\text{d}H$ nevertheless cannot equal $\text{d}q_\text{rev}$, simply because $\text{d}q_\text{rev}$ does not exist at constant $T$ and $P$.

Note that at equilibrium, there is no change of composition, $\text{d}G=0$ and $\text{d}H = \text{d}q = \text{d}q_\text{rev}$ as it should.

One way to have a reversible change of composition at constant $T$ and $P$ is to allow non-$PV$ work, such as that in an electrochemical cell.  By carefully and slowly adjusting the current, we can allow the reaction to proceed reversibly.  However, in that case $\text{d}H \neq \text{d}q$.  In the presence of non-$PV$ work, $\text{d}H = \text{d}q + \text{d}w_o$. If the non-$PV$ work allows the reaction to go reversibly, then:

\begin{align}
\text{d}H = \text{d}q_\text{rev} + \text{d}w_o
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\text{d}G &= \text{d}H - T \text{d}S \\
          &= \text{d}q_\text{rev} + \text{d}w_o - T \text{d}S \\
          &= \text{d}w_o
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

In your last line, you claim that $\text{d}H_\text{irrev} = \text{d}q_\text{irrev}$. But this cannot be true, because $\text{d}q_\text{irrev}$ is an inexact differential, and it does not then make sense to talk about $\text{d}H_\text{irrev}$ because the system’s thermodynamic state is ill-defined along irreversible paths. $\text{d}H = \text{d}q|_\text{const. P}$ only for reversible isobaric processes.

Comment: Suppose I have an ideal gas in a cylinder at temperature $T_0$ and pressure P.  The external pressure on the piston is held at P throughout the process.  I suddenly place the cylinder in contact with a bath at temperature $T_1$ and hold it in contact with the bath until the system re-equilibrates.  In this irreversible process, the work is $P\Delta V$ and, the heat added is equal to $Q=\Delta H$.  Now, same setup, except here I add heat to the system very gradually using a sequence of reservoirs and temperatures running from $T_0$ and $T_1$.  In this reversible path, $Q=\Delta H$ again.  So???

Comment: @ChesterMiller, your example involves *states* and *finite* differences $\Delta$. My answer concerns *paths* and *infinitesimal* differentials $d$.

Comment: How can you consider differential  changes in a state function like H along irreversible paths if the states along the path are not thermodynamic equilibrium states?

Comment: @ChesterMiller, that’s a good point, and I have updated my answer accordingly. The rest of my answer and my response to your proposed counterexample should still be valid, however.

Comment: I do not understand this. The derivation I've seen is exactly this: H=U+pV, so dH=dq-pdV+pdV+Vdp. So at constant pressure and temperature this becomes dH=dq. Enthalpy is used a lot in chemistry, and is always treated as a state function (also Wikipedia confirms btw :-)), depending only on initial and final state. Just like U is a state function and Delta(U) is the same for reversible and irreversible processes H should be as well. You are then basically saying that H is not a state function.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy#Relationship_to_heat

Comment: Also, Delta(H) is defined for processes such as combustion, which are not reversible.

Comment: @Stikke, read my answer carefully, and in particular my first response to ChesterMiller’s comment. $H$ is certainly a state function. Nowhere does $\Delta$ appear in my answer. The standard derivation that you’ve seen is imprecise and requires care to make it work.

Comment: @a-cyclohexane-molecule, the OP is correct that $\text{d}H_\text{irrev} = \text{d}q_\text{irrev}$ at constant $T$ and $P$, when $P$ of the system equals $P$ of the surroundings throughout the change of state, and no non-PV work is done.  There are many cases in thermodynamics when an inexact differential is equivalent to an exact differential.  For instance, when no work is done and only heat is exchanged, $\text{d}U =\text{d}q$. Since $\text{d}U$ is path independent, in this case $\text{d}q$ is also path independent.

Comment: @ratsalad, at constant T and p, I’m not sure how you plan on perturbing your system. Even if you remove the constraint of constant T, how do you intend on interpreting $dH_\text{irrev}$? Your subsequent example is correct, but it misses the gist of my argument. Reversible or not, the equalities $\Delta H = q|_\text{const. p}$ and $\Delta U = q|_\text{const. V}$ hold. I am stating that their differential analogues do not in an irreversible situation.

Comment: @a-cyclohexane-molecule Given the conventional constraints for using H and G (i.e., constant $T$ and $P$, $P_\text{sys} = P_\text{surr}$, only $PV$ work), it is straightforward to derive $\text{d}H = \text{d}q$ (see OP comment a few above).  The derivation does not assume reversibility, so the differential equality holds for irreversible processes.  This equality $\text{d}H = \text{d}q$ is the fundamental basis of constant pressure thermochemistry and calorimetry.

Comment: At constant $T$ and $P$, the system is typically perturbed by a change of composition (e.g., a chemical reaction) that releases or absorbs heat (exo/endothermic reaction).  Any out-of-equilibrium chemical reaction is by definition irreversible.

Comment: @ratsalad, the OP’s derivation most certainly assumes reversibility upon taking dw = -pdV. The equality $\Delta H = q|_\text{const. P}$ forms the basis of calorimetry, not its differential analogue. You are correct in stating that changes in N can perturb the system, but I don’t understand why you have chosen to fix T and introduce N, rather than allow T to vary and not worry about N altogether.

Comment: @a-cyclohexane-molecule $\text{d}w = -P \text{d}V$ does not assume reversibility, it only assumes that $P_\text{sys} = P_\text{surr}$.  Which could be occurring quasistatically.   Note that $P_\text{sys} = P_\text{surr}$ can be true during an irreversible change of composition.  The OP fixed $T$ and $P$, and that is also the conventional constraint when using Gibbs free energy $G$.  $G$ is typically used by chemists and biochemists since the reactions they are interested in (changing $N$) frequently  occur at constant room temp or body temp and constant atmospheric pressure.

Comment: @ratsalad, I must admit that I have never found a fully satisfactory distinction between quasistatic and reversible. My understanding is that quasistatic implies a well-mixed system, so that it can be said to have a thermodynamic state at any point, whereas reversible implies the same internal and external intensive parameters. From my perspective, therefore, quasistaticity is insufficient. If you interpret quasistatic a different way, please clarify this in the context of this problem.

Comment: Regarding your other points, an irreversible change of composition—-and indeed any change of composition—requires the addition of a chemical work term to the OP’s derivation, rendering it insufficient. I propose that we restrict the conversation to fixed N and varying T for simplicity. There is no reason to consider G, and hence require fixed T and p, because G is not the subject of our disagreement or indeed of the OP’s post.

Comment: Finally, while these points are worth discussing, I believe the crux of the issue can be resolved by considering what you mean by $dH_\text{irrev}$. To me, this is not a meaningful quantity, because the system state during an irreversible process is not well-defined.

Comment: Quasi-static just means that the change is slow/controlled enough for internal equilibrium of the system, which allows the internal state functions of the system to be defined, even for an irreversible process.  It is applicable here because we are assuming that the system has defined constant T and P during the change of state.

Comment: The derivation of $\text{d}H = \text{d}q$ does not require anything about a chemical work term or chemical potential.  The derivation only assumes the definition of enthalpy $H=U+PV$, the first law $\text{d}U = \text{d}q + \text{d}w$, and the constraints constant $T$ and $P$, $P_\text{sys} = P_\text{surr}$, only $PV$ work.  These constraints in fact allow a well-defined system state during an irreversible process (at least enough to conclude that $\text{d}H = \text{d}q$).

Comment: @ratsalad, in that case, our definitions of quasistatic agree, and reversibility is imposed by the condition that the internal and external pressures are equal. The derivation thus holds solely for reversible processes. There is no need for the constraint of constant temperature. I agree that you need not consider chemical work (at least when dN = 0), but if you insist on constant T and p, then the only irreversible perturbation of the system you have access to requires changing N, and hence a chemical work term.

Comment: First, reversible implies quasistatic, but not the converse.  Reversibility implies $P_\text{sys} = P_\text{surr}$, but constraining $P_\text{sys} = P_\text{surr}$ does not imply reversibility.  Second, a chemical reaction can occur in a closed system spontaneously and irreversibly without doing any work (and without requiring work to be done on it from the surroundings).  Hence there is no chemical work term required for a change of composition.

Comment: @ratsalad, the combination of (i) internal and external parameters being the same, (ii) only heat and PV work (in particular, no frictional or dissipative heating) being produced as a result of the reaction, and (iii) quasistaticity should imply reversibility. Regarding your second point, that's incorrect. There will be a term for the chemical work in the expression for energy because the number of moles of chemical species is changing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101971/discussion-between-ratsalad-and-a-cyclohexane-molecule).

Comment: @a-cyclohexane-molecule Both of the points in your last comment are incorrect, and the last one violates the first law of thermo for a closed system.  We should move to a chat at this point if we wish to continue.